# Conditional Formatting - highlight is coloring cells with no discrete match

Tags: excel

So I am trying to compare from 2 lists of values in excel and highlight matches.  Upon using the duplicate highlight function in conditional format I am getting cells highlighted that either have no match at all in the 2 columns or possibly is seeing 02 matching with 2 shown in the screenshot.  Is there any way to get EXACT matches only?  Thanks!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this is to add a separate "Match" column that does the look-up for you, then add a formula-based conditional format to the first column.  Doing that I get this:

[image]

The match formula in cell F3 is:

```
=MATCH(D3,$A$1:$A$2,0)
```

The conditional formula in cell D3 is:

```
=NOT(ISNA(F3))
```

However, for larger spreadsheets, lots of cells with conditional formatting can really slow things down.  I used to use something like this on one of my templates but later switched to a VBA formatting script that would do the same thing but only when needed.  It really depends on the size of the spreadsheet and how often the data is likely to change whether always-there conditional formatting or a run-when-needed VBA script would be better in your case.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm going to be working with a varying set of data but some of these tables are very large.  I have a similar set of data that is expiring and being updated....so lets say A1:D1 all have data and E1:H1 will be the data that is replacing the old data set.  Instead of having to search for the specific data in A1:D1 then manually updating the records, Is there a way to concatenate and search explicity for exact matches?  Sorry for the wordy question I just don't know how else I could explain it

Comment: @stevepark - In that case, the match() function will find exact matches for you, but I would leave the conditional formatting to a VBA script.  I have something similar where I've a list of ID numbers I want to find in a longer list of several hundred records.  The match() functions worked fine but the conditional formatting made the spreadsheet unusable.  How big is "very large?"  Excel is very useful, but it has it's limitations.  At a certain point you may consider ditching Excel and using a proper scripting language.